# How do I calculate the number of turns needed for a coil gun?

Tags: electromagnetism, coil

I've got 20m of 1mm in diameter copper enamel wire that I coiled around a PVC pipe as neatly as I could. I powered it with around 20V and put a small iron nail near the pipe but nothing happened. How big must my coil be and how many turns do I need for the iron nail to be attracted towards the centre? I estimated that I had around 250 turns on the PVC pipe.

Comment: 20m of 1mm wire has about 0.5 ohm. Do you have power supply with 20V/0.5ohm= 40A rating to not reach its current limit? Btw, do not supply the coil with 40A continuously because heat melts down the PVC pipe.

Comment: There are any number of posts on various sites for designs of working coil guns. Search carefully, read and learn.